# How to regexp in vim to open a compile pdf

Tags: regex, linux, vim, latex, tex

i try to

```
:! pdflatex file.tex && xdg-open file.pdf
```

in a general way with the '%' command, how to chanche the extension .tex to .pdf in vim using regexp?

```
:! pdflatex % && xdg-open ??
```

Comment: It's very unclear on what you're asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `:r` or `<` with `%` (current file name) to remove the extension.

```
:!pdflatex % && xdg-open %<.pdf
```

For more help see:

```
:h c_%
:h filename-modifiers
```